# how are @types, typescript and webpack related

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

To use an exported type in `.ts` file one has to add import it

```
 import {jQuery} from 'jQuery'
```

Now when I use this I do not get intellisense, I still need to do `npm install @types\jQuery` to get that.

So without @types, above statement just infers that during typescript bundling include this file.

Now if I install @types then without adding any other code, I do start getting intellisense.

So is it like above statement is dual purpose.

During bundling using typescript/webpack, it tells to bundle these files as dependency and during compilation, it tells to include .d.ts rather than actual code file?

Why this question: I am trying to move angular1 to typescript and I can use `angular.whatever` in `.ts` file even without importing it? Not getting why this is happening. It should give me error asking me to import angular

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: i m using `vscode`, but then tsc is run from command line, so has nothing to do with editor

Comment: This should work automatically in VS Code 1.7.2: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get your question 100% but I can try to explain a bit. The javascript runtime won't have a static check, it is just during the compilation time. If you tell typescript that your variable/function/etc. is of type 'any' then it will just allow you to do anything with it. Eventually the generated code is the same, whether it is checked or not. If you don't have corresponding variable during runtime, you will get an error. Typings are used to just "teach" ts compiler about the actual types of variable for static compilation.

So during compilation no .d.ts is included anywhere, this is just for static type check.

As to why you can access angular, I suppose it is because of d.ts contains the definition and by using @types/angular you let ts compiler know about it.

Check [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular/index.d.ts). The .d.ts files includes global variable angular, that's why you can use it without importing I think.

P.S. Not sure 100%, but seems like it is this line:

```
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;
```

You can try deleting this line and see if you get your error :)

Comment: I know that .d.ts is only for providing type information.. anyway thanks for help

Comment: You have asked about it :) `it tells to include .d.ts rather than actual code file?`. I have also edited the answer about the angular variable.